# Devise password which allows special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using devise gem for my rails3 project. I need to allow (!@#$%^&*-+?<>,.;:"'\|) these special characters in my password. Can any one help me how to write validation for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can validate like this

```
validates_format_of :password, :with => /^[A-Za-z0-9. ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ - + = ]*\z/
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to put this in my devise config file:

## first install gem / add to your gemfile

```
gem 'devise_security_extension'
```

## regex for: 1 char of A-Z, a-z and 0-9

```
config.password_regex = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/
```