# Login with devise failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-2.2

I am using devise gem for authentication and current rails version (3.2.22), so my password have some special character like '@' , after upgrade to ruby 2.2.0 i couldn't login with that credentials but that allows me to login after removing that '@', how can we rectify with ruby 2.2.0

current version which i am using

```
devise (2.2.1)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
orm_adapter (> 0.1)
railties (> 3.1)
warden (~> 1.2.1)
```

Comment: Please paste your error message at least.

Comment: which message do you want?

Answer (score 0):

See if this link helps.

[Devise password which allows special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377366/devise-password-which-allows-special-characters)

If there are any other settings that you have adjusted, please post that code as well.